# ¿Cómo despliego el ultimo elemento de una lista en python, y la suma de todos los elementos?

Tags: python, lista

Estoy con un código donde se ingrese la cantidad de elementos que va a ingresar a la lista, el programa debe leer cada uno de los elementos de la lista (números enteros) uno por línea y se van agregando a la lista. El programa debe validar que el número de elementos a ingresar sea mayor que cero, sino debe volver a pedir el valor hasta que se cumpla.

En mi entrada debe ir el número entero que corresponde al número de elementos, lo cual debe ser mayor 0 sino debe solicitarse hasta que lo sea

El programa debe desplegar el último elemento
Después, la suma de todos los elementos
Y el promedio de todos los elementos

```
lista=[]
lista_t=int(input())
if lista_t >0:
    for i in range(0, lista_t):
        numero=int(input())
        lista.append(numero)
```

Esto llevo de código, necesito ayuda en como desplegar el último elemento de mi tabla y la suma de todos los elementos

Comment: Hola. Edita, por favor, tu pregunta y añade el código con lo que has intentado y las dudas que tengas y/o errores. De esta forma la comunidad podrá ayudarte. Te invito a leer el enlace de cómo preguntar [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

> para poder ver el ultimo elemento de una lista o tupla puedes usar los subindices, siendo >el -1 el ultimo caracter. si quieres mostrarlo en pantalla
> `print(lista[-1])`
> para poder hacer la suma de todos los elementos de una lista puedes usar la funcion >predefinida sum que sumara todos los valores de la lista o tupla si estan convertidos a >int
> o puedes hacerlo con un ciclo for
> opcion 1
> `print(sum(lista))`
> opcion 2

```
for i in range len(lista):
      sumatoria += i
print(sumatoria)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    L = []
    sum = int(0)
        n = int(input('Ingrese cuantos elementos tiene la lista..'))
    while (n<1):
    n = int(input('Ingrese cuantos elementos tiene la lista..'))
    for i in range(0,n):
        x = int(input())   # ingreso un elemento
        L.append(x)     # lo agrego a la lista
        sum = sum + x
    print(L[-1])  # ultimo elemento de la lista
    print(sum)   # suma de los elementos
    print(sum/n)   # promedio (suma/cant elementos)
```

Comment: Hola Valentina, pese a que, la respuesta pueda ser correcta, una publicación que incluya únicamente código, sin explicar cómo se ha obtenido dicho resultado no es útil. Te invito a que leas, [Cómo responder adecuadamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos

Comment: Por favor, indenta correctamente el código.

Comment: ¿Qué hace este código?